# Avoid ambigous GetMapping in Spring boot Rest

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, microservices, restful-url

I have two GET Requests

```
@GetMapping
public List<Limit> getAllLimits(@RequestParam() Map<String, String> limitFilters) throws ApiException {
    if(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(limitFilters)) {
        return limitService.getAllLimits();
    }
    else {
        return limitService.getLimitBySearchFilters(limitFilters);
    }
}

@GetMapping(params = { "id", "asOfDate" })
public Limit getLimitByid(@RequestParam Long id, @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @RequestParam(value = "asOfDate", required = false) LocalDate asOfDate) throws EntityNotFoundException, ApiException {
    return limitService.getLimitById(id, asOfDate);
}

@GetMapping({"/{pid}"})
public Limit getLimitByPid(@PathVariable Long pid) throws EntityNotFoundException, ApiException {
    return limitService.getLimitByPid(pid);
}
```

- http://localhost:8080/limit url goes to getAllLimits(@RequestParam() Map limitFilters) - this is correct
- http://localhost:8080/limit/1 goes to getLimitByPid() - this is correct
- http://localhost:8080/limit?id=1&asOfDate=2018-07-12 goes to getLimitByid - this is correct

However, please note that `asOfDate` is optional
So, `http://localhost:8080/limit?id=1` goes to `getAllLimits(@RequestParam() Map<String, String> limitFilters)` whereas I want it to route to `getLimitByid()` method

How can I achive this? Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I found way to do this finally:

```
@GetMapping(params = { "id" })
public Limit getLimitByid(@RequestParam Long id, @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) @RequestParam(name = "asOfDate") Optional<LocalDate> opAsOfDate) throws EntityNotFoundException, ApiException {
    LocalDate asOfDate = opAsOfDate.orElse(LocalDate.now());
    return limitService.getLimitById(id, asOfDate);
}

@GetMapping({"/{pid}"})
public Limit getLimitByPid(@PathVariable Long pid) throws EntityNotFoundException, ApiException {
    return limitService.getLimitByPid(pid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html), `@RequestParam Map<String, String> limitFilters` tells spring to map any request params to this `Map`:

> If the method parameter is `Map<String, String>` or
>   `MultiValueMap<String, String>` and a parameter name is not specified,
>   then the map parameter is populated with all request parameter names
>   and values.

So imagine you would have `id` param in your filter. It will mess up your controller. So the easiest way would be to change paths

Comment: any reference for this

Comment: edited my answer. Actually the request `http://localhost:8080/limit?id=1&asOfDate=2018-07-12` could be handled by `getAllLimits`, don't know why it works as you expected